# Signalr on Azure: service bus required for calling a single client?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, signalr

I read that Signalr on Azure requires a service bus implementation (e.g. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Azure-service-bus) for scalability purpose.

However, my server only makes callbacks to a single client (the caller):

```
// Invoke a method on the calling client
Caller.addMessage(data);
```

If don't need Signalr's broadcasting functionality, is an underlaying service bus still necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Service Bus dependency is not something specific to Azure. Any time you have multiple servers in play, some of your signalR clients will have created their connection to a specific server. If you want to keep multiple servers in sync something needs to handle the server to server real time communication. The pub-sub model of service bus lines up with this requirement quite well.

> dfowleR lists a specific case of this in the comments. Make sure you read down that far!

If you are running on a single server (without the sla on Azure) signalR will work just fine on a Cloud Service Web Role as well as the new Azure Web Sites. I did a [screencast](http://developusing.net/2012/06/08/DevelopingSinglePageRealTimeWebsitesOnWindowsAzure.aspx) on this simple scenario that does not take on a service bus dependency, but only runs on a single server.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I do need multiple servers, but I don't need to sync data between them. I understand that I can use Signalr as-is, no service bus needed, correct?

Comment: The problem is if you end up using longpolling for whatever reason and you get load balanced to another server then you'll need the replication, of you'll miss messages.

Comment: @dfowler exactly what I wanted to know, thanks. Amazing work on Signalr btw :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to support the load balance scenario, is it possible to enstablish a "server to server" SignalR PersistConnection  between multiple instances (ie on Azure) ?
If so, we can use a SQL Azure Table where all instances register at startup, so newest can connect to previous ones.